# How to change permission on a System owned folder?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm working on a Win XP machine.
By mistake I changed the permission of a folder in a way that only System user has full control of that folder.
My user has only read permission even if I'm an administrator.
How can I take back control of this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Advanced permissions and then Take Ownership of the folder.  You can then apply whatever permissions you wish